# Is there any way to add meta tags in angular app without using angular universal.?

Tags: angular, seo, meta-tags, angular-universal

I started an angular project and have done a lot of work but now I realize the issue with meta tags in angular. 
I added **`og`** **`tags`** and meta tags using different modules, but as per my research, they are not SEO friendly. the solution says angular universal. Is there any other way to add meta tags and **`og`** tags to which can be visible in view source page as using basic meta-services the tags are visible on inspect element but not on view source page.

Comment: Could you add some code here.

Answer (score 1):

Schema structured data is a way to provide additional metadata that describes our content on our pages.This metadata can then be used by search engines like Google to provide rich SEO snippets to users

To use JSON-LD, we have to use the Angular DOMSanitizer service to bypass Angular to allow script tags in our template.

For more details check this: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-seo-with-schema-and-json-ld

Comment: will this be able to add meta tags dynamically in head html tag?

Comment: if you want to make seo friendly website it will work check